# AngularJS Radio button not binding to model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am facing a problem with the binding of a radio button to the MVC model when using AngularJS, all other fields are binding successfully to the MVC model but the radio button is just not binding. Please advice where I got my wires mixed up.

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in experienceModel">
                <td><input type="text" name="StartDate" ng-model="item.StartDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'" id="date_teachingStart{{$index}}"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="EndDate" ng-model="item.EndDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'" id="date_teachingEnd{{$index}}"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="SubjectArea" ng-model="item.SubjectArea"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Position" ng-model="item.Position"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Institution" ng-model="item.Institution"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="City" ng-model="item.City"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Country" ng-model="item.Country"/></td>
                <td class="centerAlign"><input type="radio" name="item.IsCurrent" value="{{$index}}" ng-model="selected.item" id="radio_experience[{{$index}}]" /></td>                    
                <td><a class="removeRow" title="Delete item" href="" ng-click="removeRow()"></a></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="CVId" ng-model="item.CVID" /></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="ExperienceID" ng-model="item.ExperienceID" /></td>
            </tr>
```

**script**

```
 var experienceModel = <%: Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model.TeachingExperience)) %>
     app.value("experienceModel", experienceModel);
```

**Angular Controller**

```
 app.controller('TeachingController', ['$scope', 'experienceModel',
function ($scope, experienceModel) {

        $scope.counter = 0;            

        $scope.selected = {};

        $scope.experienceModel = experienceModel;

        // Set the selected value to reflect initial data 
        $scope.experienceModel.forEach(function (item, index) {
            if (item.IsCurrent) {
                $scope.selected.item = index;
            }
        });

        if ($scope.experienceModel == null) {
            $scope.experienceModel = [{ 'ExperienceID': '', 'CVID': '', 'ExperienceCategoryId': '', 'StartDate': '', 'EndDate': '', 'SubjectArea': '', 'NoOfDays': '', 'Position': '', 'Programme': '', 'KnowledgeArea': '', 'Institution': '', 'Client': '', 'City': '', 'Country': '', 'IsCurrent': '' }];
        }

        if ($scope.experienceModel.length == 0) {
            $scope.experienceModel.push({ 'ExperienceID': '', 'CVID': '', 'ExperienceCategoryId': '', 'StartDate': '', 'EndDate': '', 'SubjectArea': '', 'NoOfDays': '', 'Position': '', 'Programme': '', 'KnowledgeArea': '', 'Institution': '', 'Client': '', 'City': '', 'Country': '', 'IsCurrent': '' });
        }

        $scope.$watch('selected.item', function (index) {
            $scope.items.forEach(function (item, i) {
                item.isCurrent = i === parseInt(index);
            });
        });

        $scope.counter = 1;

    $scope.addRow = function () {
        $scope.experienceModel.push({ 'ExperienceID': '', 'CVID': '', 'ExperienceCategoryId': '', 'StartDate': '', 'EndDate': '', 'SubjectArea': '', 'NoOfDays': '', 'Position': '', 'Programme': '', 'KnowledgeArea': '', 'Institution': '', 'Client': '', 'City': '', 'Country': '', 'IsCurrent': '' });
        $scope.counter++;
    }
    $scope.removeRow = function () {
        var row = $(this);
        $scope.experienceModel.splice(row[0].$index, 1);
        $scope.counter--;
    }
}]);
```

Comment: you need to use ``ng-model`` instead of the value attribute?

Comment: refer this  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

Answer (score 2):

"The thing" that's **responsible for two-way data binding in AngularJS is `ng-model`**. You should set this attribute on all form fields that you want the user to interact with.

It will take care of setting fields' values for you, so to speak - so the `value` attributes should be removed. You can have **`ng-model` or `value`** but if you do decide to only set the value (it makes sense in some cases, e.g. `readonly` fields), it will be bound in one direction only - it will react to changes to the model but not be able to change the model.

Ok, after this theoretical introduction, here's a possible solution:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

    // Sample data
    $scope.items = [
      {name: 'First', isCurrent: false},
      {name: 'Second', isCurrent: false},
      {name: 'Third', isCurrent: false},
      {name: 'Fourth', isCurrent: false}
    ];

    /* Object to track selected things. (It's better to use objects
     * rather than plain variables to avoid problems with variable's scope) */
    $scope.selected = {};

    // Set the selected value to reflect initial data 
    $scope.items.forEach(function(item, index) {
      if (item.isCurrent) {
        $scope.selected.item = index;
      }
    });

    /* If selected item changes, set corresponding item's 
     * isCurrent property to true and all others to false */
    $scope.$watch('selected.item', function(index) {
      $scope.items.forEach(function(item, i) {
        item.isCurrent = i === parseInt(index);
      });
    });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
      {{ item.name }}
      <label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="selected.item" value="{{ $index }}">current
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <pre>{{ items | json }}</pre>
</body>
```

Ok, so after merging this and things we've clarified in comments, your html code should look like this:

```
<!-- (...) -->
<td><input type="text" name="city" ng-model="item.City" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="country" ng-model="item.Country" /></td>
<td class="centerAlign"><input type="radio" ng-model="selected.item" /></td>
<td><a class="removeRow" title="Delete item" href="" ng-click="removeRow($index)"></a></td>
<!-- (...) -->
```

Mind some "bonus" improvements:

- **you don't need to use `href="javascript:void(0)"`** when working with AngularJS. `href=""` will be sufficient (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/a)
- when removing a row it's easiest to **just pass iteration's `$index`** to your `removeRow()` function
- if you're not using Angular's validation, you won't need `name` attributes
- if you're not using labels (in particular `<label` **`for="sth"`**`>`) you won't nee `id` attributes

Comment: What would my controller and html then look like? Should I do a foreach in the controller and change my html to. 'ng-model="experienceModel{{$index}}.IsCurrent" '

Comment: @Righardt I've updated the answer with working example (you can run it here to see how it works). Btw. in your `ng-repeat` you don't need to reference certain items as `experienceModel[{{$index}}]` you can use the iteration variable you've chosen and Angular will understand that. So for example in your code instead of `name="TeachingExperience[{{$index}}].StartDate"` you can write `name="item.StartDate"`. Much easier for the eyes :)

Comment: thanks, I have changed to name=item.StartDate, How should I implement ng-model in the controller and in my HTML?

Comment: I've updated my answer with example of changed html code. As for the controller, you can leave it pretty much as it was, only add the logic responsible for this `selected.item` (so the part with creating `selected` object, `$scope.$watch`ing of its change, and iterating over your `experienceModel` array to set the initial `selected.item` value. And of course the `$scope.items` from my example is the same as your `$scope.experienceModel`. That's it.

Comment: Please see the updated changes in my code. The values are pulling thru and displaying correctly, however it seems that the two-way binding is not working. The experience model in the MVC controller is null.